# static kernel datastructure

Tags: linux, kernel

I know that linux kernel has system call table
to handle system call, and Interrupt descriptor table to
handle interrupts.

these two tables should not be changed after booting process.

is there any other data structure other than system call table and IDT
which kernel uses similarly? 
(which should not be modified after setup process)

thank you in advance